# Runtime permission dialogue not showing on some devices having marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

Hello I am facing issue that Some devices not show run time permission.what would be the issue?
I am facing on some devices and app crashes.but when I go to settings and allow permissions then it is fine

Comment: crash log + what are the devices? and how sure are you that its device issue & not code issue, and finally, if you talking about Xiomi devices, then you gonna have a nightmare.

Comment: you also need to add this permissions to manifest...have you done this or do you just request at runtime?

Comment: Post *error log* or *Logcat*. And make sure what @Opiatefuchs Sir is suggesting check and go through that part.

Comment: on nexus 5 it is working fine and many more.but my client have samsung s7,Lg g2 having 6.0
.it just crash.


java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedReader.close()' on a null object reference
1at com.bugsense.trace.Utils.manageUid(Unknown Source)
2at com.bugsense.trace.BugSenseHandler$1.run(Unknown Source)
3at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: if it is code issue then why it is running on some device haivng 6.0.1 @jay

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to handle run time permission is via **RxPermission**.

Try with **[RxPermission](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions)** will solve you issue

Comment: on nexus 5 it is working fine and many more.but my clinet have samsung s7 having 6.0

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] permissions = new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS,
        Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW,
        Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK,
        Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY,
        Manifest.permission.VIBRATE,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,

};
 private boolean checkPermissions() {
    int result;
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String p : permissions) {
        result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), p);
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
        }
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(root, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // selectImage();
            // isPermission = true;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: my code s working on some devices and some devices it is crashing.

Comment: ohk which device have crashing?

Comment: can u check your Target Api Level?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedReader.close()' on a null object reference 1at com.bugsense.trace.Utils.manageUid(Unknown Source) 2at com.bugsense.trace.BugSenseHandler$1.run(Unknown Source) 3at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: 25 target level

Comment: there is may be not Permission issue

Comment: i will show you.but the point is that code is working on other apps.the same code

Comment: ohk there is no Permission error in marshmallow for this error

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Permissions without dialog at the first start of your App programmatically.

```
private void setPermission(string permission){
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/su -c pm grant " + [your package name] + " " + permission);
            process.waitFor();
            Log.d(TAG, "permission exec done " + process.exitValue());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call it with:

```
setPermission("android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW");
```

I'm not 100 % sure if you need sudo.

Comment: I am facing this error with above code

java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/system/bin/su, -c, pm, grant, "package name", android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION] Working Directory: null Environment: null